# MailChimp: I can't type into sign up form input field from Mailchimp. Why?

Tags: forms, reactjs, input, mailchimp

I am trying to use an embedded form from Mailchimp in my code, specifically the 'horizontal' style. I've had to edit the code a little in order to make it compatible with ES6, as I'm using GatsbyJS. The problem is that the form show up fine on my browser, but I can't type into the input field... why is this? and how could I fix this?

here is my code for the form:

```
    <div className='row bottom-margin-small'>
        <div className='newssub-wrapper col-sm-10 offset-sm-1'>
            <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                <form action="https://fruitcakeblog.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d57c0ac89b6b66e99eb7cb07c&amp;id=daea937c97" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" className="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll" style={{background: '#fff', clear: 'left', fontSize: '14px', width: '100%'}}>
                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" className="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required />
                        <div style={{position: 'absolute', left: '-5000px'}} aria-hidden="true">
                            <input type="text" name="b_d57c0ac89b6b66e99eb7cb07c_daea937c97" tabindex="-1" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="clear">
                            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" className="button" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and it turns out the [Gatsby team is working on implementing support](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/3333). There is a small React library from [Julien Bouquillon](https://github.com/revolunet) called [React Mailchimp Subscribe](https://github.com/revolunet/react-mailchimp-subscribe) that might allow you to implement a form by building it using JSX instead of HTML that you copy/paste from the Mailchimp Form Builder.